# Wordpress Permalinks not working in Apache2 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: permalinks

In my local machine, wordpress permalinks not working. After research I found that wordpress not creating .htaccess file.

For this I followed below steps.

1. Manually create a "`.htaccess`" file and save it in your main WordPress directory. (This is the one with the wp-admin, wp-includes, and wp-content folders.)
2. Go to the Ubuntu terminal and type:

   sudo chown -v :www-data "/FilePathHere/.htaccess"

You should see a line printed saying that the (group) file ownership has been changed to www-data (Apache2).

3. Give Apache2 write access to the file:

   sudo chmod -v 664 "/FilePathHere/.htaccess"

You should see a line printed saying that the mode of the file has been retained.

4. Next, we have to allow WordPress to write to the .htaccess file by enabling mod_write in the Apache2 server. Type the following in the terminal:

   sudo a2enmod rewrite

You should see a line printed saying that it is enabling mod rewrite and reminding you to restart the web server

5. So let's do that. Restart the web server, Apache2, for the changes to take effect by typing:

   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

We are all done with the command line prompt; you can close the command line window now.

5. Go into your WordPress admin panel (i.e. `http://Domain/wp-admin`). Go to the Settings --> Permalinks and select the permalink format of your choice. Hit the "Save Changes" button.

All steps were successful. But even that Permalinks not worked.

Is anything else settings required to work permalinks properly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In terminal type:

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Find:

`<Directory /var/www/>`

And make sure the `AllowOverride` directive is set to `All`.

Comment: You're awesome!

Comment: sudo service apache2 restart   ---- afterward to make the change take effect.

Comment: I had to change `AllowOveride` to `All` for `/var/www/html`

Comment: Just to note this is *still* a solution if your WordPress site is running from a *separate* conf file in /sites-enabled, and you already have `AllowOverride All` within a `<Directory />` block in that, and are thinking to yourself, but why would I need to edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf as well…?

Comment: This solution by SLH still works 2020

Comment: This solution worked with me, 2021! :D
Ubuntu 20.04 - apache2

Comment: Thank you @HeatfanJohn your solution helped me. It needs the project directory access

Answer (score 7):

In order to follow `.htaccess` redirects, it should be mentioned that Apache's `<mod_rewrite>` module needs to be enabled.

You can do this from command line on the server using the following commands:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i cannot express the amount of happiness i just got from reading this answer